# Try to read raid 1 (mirror) disk

Tags: raid, mdadm

I have the raid 1 (mirror) disks coming from an enclosure that stopped working.

So I am trying to recover the data putting one disk into a USB adapter.

When I connect the adapter /dev adds item sdb, so I suppose this is my raid drive.

But fdisk -l does not show it. Gparted does not show it.

Worse,

```
sudo mdadm  --misc --examine /dev/sdb
```

gives

```
mdadm: cannot open /dev/sdb: No medium found
```

I tried with various computers and various OSs, but the result is always the same.
The other disk is just the same.

Any hope?

The enclosure is model RSS2TJ by ONNTO corp in Taiwan

Comment: Is the enclosure that stopped working or is it a failure of the drives themselves and/or file corruption (which inevitably would be mirrored so trying either of the RAID1 drives gives the same result)? Please [edit] the question and add details about the "enclosure" as some (many) use some proprietary stuff.

Comment: So, ChanganAuto you seem to suggest that the enclosure corrupted the disks. Well, in this case there is nothing to do. But it was a bad idea to buy that enclosure in the first place. Worst, this raid 1 thing is not for security really. This is the second time I had problems with raid 1, the first time it was a NAS. That time I was able to recover the files,  but not easy.

Comment: Not really. I was asking because the 2 possibilities should be considered.